# Horrible VM performance on HDD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, virtual-machine, performance

Currently I'm noticing a horrible performance when I put my VM's on my internal HDD. The HDD is split into 3 Partitions (D:, E:, F:) and have a maxiumum capacity of 500GB by 7200rpm.

File copy from the M.2 SSD to the HDD and vice versa is pretty fast (around 115 MB/s) but as soon as I start a VM the usage stuck between 98% - 100%. For now I have no idea what is causing the behaviour and I don't know if this is normal.

Further more information about the host system:

- OS: Windows 10 1809
- CPU: i5-8250U (yes, it is a laptop)
- RAM: Single Bank 8GB DDR4 2400MHz
- SSD: M.2 Samsung EVO860 (256GB)
- HDD: 500GB 7200rpm (about 8 - 10 years old)
- Hypervisor: VirualBox

For any idea I would be thankfull.

Comment: Performance in a HDD is always way worse than SSD. A VM will add to that.

Comment: What OS are you running in the VM? Are you using Hyper-V or Oracle VirtualBox? How much RAM are you allocating to the VM? It sounds like a paging issue, in that the VM is just paging to disk as it's out of RAM.

Comment: @spikey_richie Oh crap! Sorry I forgot to name the hypervisor. It is VirtualBox. I only test Win Server 2016 Standard for know. I gave it 2Gb of RAM what was sufficient while running the VM from the SSD.

Comment: Right, but paging out to the SSD would be OK as it's performant. Paging to a regular HDD is not. What if you allow the VM to use 4GB or RAM?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yeah that’s an idea. Further I will turn of the swapping hopefully it will give a benefit instead of problems. I will update the question tomorrow

Comment: What's the verdict?

Comment: @spikey_richie Thank you! I have post a answere for all who may have a simillar issue.

Answer (score 0):

At first, thanks to @spikey_richie!
Adapting the VM to 4 GB RAM gave a little performance increase. Further I disabled the SWAP file and the disk usage dropped immediately to 5% - 10% in idle. I guess what also could be a "performace eater" is the dynamically VM disk. Creating a fixed size may increse the performance also.

Comment: You will unlikely see any increase any performance by using a fixed size virtual HDD.